# Google Maps in C# Visual Studio application

Tags: c#, forms, google-maps, user-interface

For my university  I have to create an application that for the User Interfaces paper that I'm doing. I want to create an application that focuses on Africa and allows the user to plot on the map some points of interest.

First thing first though, i need to be able to get the Google maps API working in a form. Does anyone have any idea how I would do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google maps is based on JavaScript. You will need to embed the maps objects into the page and use it that way.

A good starting point would be http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html and the most basic of tutorials is available at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#HelloWorld.

I would definatley recommend then links above and then move onto something like http://googlemap.codeplex.com/. It's better to know what's going on underneath before abstracting it away.

Comment: Thanks I've been playing with this for a few hours and its going great. Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you may wish to check out GMap.net (the website is not GMap.net: http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/)

> GMap.NET is great and Powerful, Free, cross platform, open source .NET
>   control. Enable use routing, geocoding and maps from Coogle, Yahoo!,
>   Bing, OpenStreetMap, ArcGIS, Pergo, SigPac, Yandex, Mapy.cz, Maps.lt,
>   iKarte.lv, NearMap, OviMap, CloudMade in Windows Forms & Presentation,
>   supports caching and runs on windows mobile!

I've used this before with WinForms and found it pretty handy.  I suggest this because parts of Africa may be better served by different map vendors.

Comment: This looks to be a fully fledged application. For our project we have to design the UI our selves. So this doesn't seem appropriate? Thanks though :)

Comment: @Sean It's a control. It's open source. Be lazy! Use it!

Comment: Sean, it's most definitely not an application.  It's a control that's been designed to be easily integrated within YOUR application!